# Is there an AWS CLI command to possibly get UserName from just a resource ARN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

We have folks that don't like to use tags when building things in AWS, so the problem is we need to go ascertain the UserName of the person who used the resource, is there a CLI command that we can use if we have the resource ARN?  Sure, we could look in cloud trail but that's a cumbersome process, need something less painful.  I'm open to anyway to do this, if someone has a boto3 script that would work as well.

Comment: Cloudtrial is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct relationship between a resource in AWS and the IAM entity that created it.

When a request is sent to AWS to create a resource (eg an Amazon S3 bucket or an Amazon EC2 instance), IAM verifies that the credentials being used have permission to create the resource. These credentials could be associated with an IAM User, IAM Role, Federated identity, etc.

If the entity making the request has permission to create the resource, then the resource is created. The resource is associated with the AWS Account that generated the credentials. **There is no association stored between the resource that was created and the user/entity that requested its creation.**

The only link between the user and the resource would be a record in AWS CloudTrail that details the API request to create the resource, together with details of the user/entity that made the API request.

Comment: John, Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I kind of thought that would be the case but would it be possible of instead of a CLI command, a script that would sort through AWS CloudTrail for that UserName?  Sure, I could use the console to find the arns and the user associated with it but that seems like a waste of time, that being said, I have not seen a script that actually does that.